# Clojure Spec to parse Reducible

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec, transducer

The doc of `clojure.spec.alpha/+` says:

> Returns a regex op that matches one or more values matching
> pred. Produces a vector of matches

And I can use it like this:

```
erdos=> (s/conform (s/+ (s/cat :e #{\a \b \c})) (seq "abc"))
[{:e \a} {:e \b} {:e \c}]
```

In the next step, I want to generalize it to run on Reducible values instead of sequences. But it will not work:

```
erdos=> (s/conform (s/+ (s/cat :e #{\a \b \c})) "abc")
:clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
```

How could I use clojure.spec [regular expression operators](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences) on Reducibles instead of sequences? (but without creating temporary sequences.) Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are going for here. A string is not a "sequence", hence you need `seq`.

Comment: Yes, a String us not a sequence, but it is a Reducible. I am trying to generalize parsing with spec.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [conformer](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/conformer) that converts the input (e.g. a string) to a sequence. Use [and](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/and) to compose it with the spec that operates on the sequence:

```
(s/def ::seq-from-string (s/conformer #(if (string? %) (seq %) ::s/invalid)
                                      #(apply str %)))


(s/conform (s/and ::seq-from-string
                  (s/+ (s/cat :e #{\a \b \c})))
           "abc")
;; => [{:e \a} {:e \b} {:e \c}]

(s/unform (s/and ::seq-from-string
                 (s/+ (s/cat :e #{\a \b \c})))
          [{:e \a} {:e \b} {:e \c}])
;; => "abc"
```

Here is a more complex example with `coll-of` on top of that spec:

```
(s/conform (s/coll-of (s/and ::seq-from-string
                             (s/+ (s/cat :e #{\a \b \c}))))
           ["a" "bb"])
;; => [[{:e \a}] [{:e \b} {:e \b}]]
```

**By the way**, I am not sure why you want to avoid creating a temporary sequence around the string. When creating a sequence from a string, e.g. `(seq "abc")`, a lightweight sequence object [StringSeq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/StringSeq.java) gets created that wraps the underlying string. I don't see the problem with that.